# Why won't my java Minecraft plugin register in the server?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Alright, so I decided to learn some code for fun and followed a tutorial for a simple hello command. I am using server.pro to run the server to test my plugin and originally coded it in Java SE-15 and Spigot 1.16.5. When I uploaded the jar file, it would not show up in the /plugins list on the server. I can choose what java to run the server on and realized it only goes up to Java 11, so I recoded it using the Java SE-11 system library with Spigot 1.16.5. Whatever I do, it will not show up on the plugins list regardless of how many times I reload the server and run the /bukkit:reload command. I am not very knowledgeable about how bukkit and spigot interact, or if my code is just wrong. Thanks in advance! [server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8mhB.png)
[more server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGm42.png)

EDIT: I checked the logs and can gather that something is invalid in my plugin.yml file. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K7HC.png) is the error message. It says I am missing some colons but they are there. I'm so close to making this work, please help!
Code:

EDIT 2: I don't think I am as close as I thought I was. Now [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtGnI.png) error is running. Do I need to change a version?

Main.java file:

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.swagmoneyloch.feefee.commands.HelloCommand;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new HelloCommand(this);
        
    }
}
```

HelloCommand.Java:

```
import me.swagmoneyloch.feefee.*;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class HelloCommand implements CommandExecutor {
    
    private Main plugin; 
    
    public HelloCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("hello").setExecutor(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
            sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
            return true;
        }
        
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        
        if (p.hasPermission("hello.use")) {
            p.sendMessage("Hello!");
            return true;
        } else {
            p.sendMessage("You do not have permission to execute this command.");
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

plugin.yml:

```
version: 1.0
author: swagmoneyloch
main: me.swagmoneyloch.feefee.Main
description: Our first minecraft spigot plugin!

commands:
  hello:
    aliases: [hi]
    description: This is the hello command!
```

Comment: Build against Java 8 (1.8) and are you sure that's your plugin.yml? The error doesn't match up with the contents you provided.

Comment: Where your `name` attribute in your `plugin.yml` ? It is necessary... aprt from that you should change Java version.

Answer (score 1):

In your plugin.yml you need an API version.
Plugin.yml wiki: [plugin.yml spigot wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/#:%7E:text=The%20plugin.,All%20attributes%20are%20case%20sensitive.)

You seem fairly new at making a plugin with java. Here's a tutorial that also works in 1.16. [How to make a spigot 1.15 plugin pt.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4W4drYdb4Q)

After looking at the error again, you need a space between the main and the directory to main.

Answer (score 0):

For the questions before edit 2, see @BlitzDBS answer.

For Edit 2 it seems like your server is running java 8 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) and your plugin was compiled for java 15, so you have to tell your IDE (Eclipse/IntelliJ/...) to compile it with java 8.